# ¿Cómo puedo leer un archivo zip comprimido que tiene contraseña en R Studio?

Tags: r, rstudio

Quiero abrir un archivo zip que tiene contraseña en R Studio.

Tengo el siguiente código, donde diarios es un archivo comprimido con contraseña que contiene una archivo .csv del mismo nombre:

getZip("datos/diarios.zip", password = "israel")

A connection with
description "C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c unzip -p -P israel datos/diarios.zip" class "pipe"
mode "r"
text "text"
opened "closed"
can read "yes"
can write "yes"

Si coloco la función read.csv

read.csv(getZip("datos/diarios.zip", password = "israel"))

R me regresa esto:

read.csv(getZip("datos/diarios.zip", password = "israel")) Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote, : no lines available in input

De antemano, gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: ¿Para que sistema Operativo?

Comment: En windows 10. Intenté hacerlo con la función getZip en R studio, pero no me regresa el archivo csv que quiero, sino una lista. Pondré en una respuesta el código que tengo y lo que R me regresa. Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: ¿Qué hay dentro del Zip? ¿un archivo? ¿varios? ¿de qué tipo?